# Check for template fails because "No templates used to render the response"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, tdd

I am working through Test-Driven Development with Python by Harry J. W. Percival. I have a Django view with the following code:

```
def view_list(request, list_id):
        list_ = List.objects.get(id=list_id)
        items = Item.objects.filter(list=list_)
        return render(request, 'list.html', {'items':items})
```

And the following Django test:

```
def test_uses_list_template(self):
        list_ = List.objects.create()
        response = self.client.get('/lists/%d' % (list_.id,))
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'list.html')
```

urls.py has the following entry:

```
url(r'^lists/(.+)/$', views.view_list, name='view_list'),
```

The test fails with the following error:

```
self.fail(msg_prefix + "No templates used to render the response")
AssertionError: No templates used to render the response
```

This was very surprising, because the view rendered successfully when I used the browser to evaluate it manually. And an automated functional test worked without error.

I looked at the HTTP server, and it was showing a redirect for a circumstance similar to this test:
[time] "GET /lists/2 HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[time] "GET /lists/2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 476

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The test is failing for the somewhat arbitrary reason that the URL is `/lists/%d` instead of `/lists/%d/` (notice the trailing slash on the second URL.) Therefore, `self.client.get` is resulting in a redirect (301) instead of success (200). Change the test using the slash at the end.

```
response = self.client.get('/lists/%d/' % (list_.id,))
```

Also note that on [obeythetestinggoat.com](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_working_incrementally.html) Percival states "Django has some built-in code to issue a permanent redirect (301) whenever someone asks for a URL which is almost right, except for a missing slash."